# Using as in the TSQLQuery

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4

I've been evaluating Delphi XE4 (compiling against win32, but final platform will be iOS) and I need to create SQLite database (no problem with that) and make some queries. This is one query I'd like to use:

```
  select id as _id, name, note as description from notes
```

And this is my code:

```
  q := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    q.SQLConnection := MainForm.sqlite1;
    q.SQL.Text := sql;
    q.Open;
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
```

The problem is that query returns original field names (id, name, note), not the one I used (_id, name, description).

```
  q.Fields[0].FieldName = 'id' //it should be _id
  q.Fields[2].FieldName = 'note' //it should be description
```

That makes all sorts of problems. Using

```
  count(*) as myfield
```

returns

```
q.Fields[0].FieldName = Column0 //it should be myfield
```

that is not acceptable.

Anybody had same problems?

Comment: Does it change if you use `SELECT +id AS _id, ...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the proper alias names of the fields, you must add the `ColumnMetaDataSupported` param to the Params property of the [`TSQLConnection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection)component with the `False` value.

[image]

Comment: Great! But is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I know the answer because i had the same issue some time ago, AFAIK there is not a QC report for this. So you can report this issue.